# Why is it difficult to evolve an interface?

Tags: c#-4.0, interface

I wanted to know why is this true :

**Adding a method to an interface will break all of it's implementations ... ??? ... Once an interface is shipped, you don't get the chance to change it without breaking code that used that interface. ...**

Have come across this stuff in many forums discussion, but none explain how..

If i add any method to an interface (say IMyInterface) and just add functionality of the method to class/classes that implements this interface then how is it breaking my code? .. its just  simple! ...is'nt it? .. (adding method signature to interface and implementing them in classes) , ..... just like i add a method to some class to extend its functionality and my code will get updated. 
Of course the purpose of class and interfaces when designing a problem are different.

Answer (score 2):

If you provide both the interface and the implementation and the code is completely internal to your application, the problem is mostly theoretical. The problem becomes real when you provide the interface in your dll and someone else provides the implementation in their dll. An example of when this might happen is with a plugin system or a device driver.

The two dll's are linked at run time when the program starts up. If you updated the interface in a new version of your dll, then the class compiled into an old version of the implementation dll is no longer valid for that interface and the program will fail to start. People are then locked into your old version until their implementation dll (which may come from a different supplier) is updated to reflect the new version.

Comment: Barend Garvelink: Thanks for explaining ... I hope it is not a bad question at stackOverflow .. or is it?